# How to update Objects using SqlConnection

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new in `ASP.NET` and I would like to update `SQL object` by user's `id`. I read about `Entity Framework`, but I am used to use `SqlConnection`. User's id is valid, because the same Id I am using in same `Controller` for different `CRUD` action. My problem is that I am still getting `500 Internal Server exception` and I think the main problem is in Controller, especially here in header of the method.

```
 public IActionResult Put(int eventId, [FromBody] Event eventData, int userId)
```

I would kindly appreciate any help or opinion or setting to the right direction.

```
[HttpPut]
            [Route("/api/calendar/event/put/{eventId}/{userId}")]
            // eventId is id of the event I want to update, eventData is object with new 
            //data to be updated 
            public IActionResult Put(int eventId, [FromBody] Event eventData, int userId)
            {
                try
                {
                    eventData.Id = eventId;
                    events.Update(eventData, userId);
                    return Ok();
                }
                catch (InvalidInput ex)
                {
                    // log the exception or return an error response
                    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, ex.Message);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // log the exception or return an error response
                    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message);
                }
            }
```

**React component:**

```
const EditEvent = ({ initialValues, handleUpdate, onClose, isOpen, onReload, userId }) => {
    const [id, setId] = useState(initialValues?.id || null);
    const [eventName, setEventName] = useState(initialValues?.eventName || "");
    const [eventDate, setEventDate] = useState(initialValues?.eventDate || "");
    const [category, setCategory] = useState(initialValues?.category || "");
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");

    const handleDescriptionChange = (event) => {
        setEventName(event.target.value);
    };

    const handleDateChange = (event) => {
        setEventDate(event.target.value);
    };


    const onUpdate = (updatedEvent) => {
        axios
            .put(`/api/calendar/event/put/${updatedEvent.id}/${userId}`, updatedEvent)
            .then((response) => {
                // handle successful response
                console.log( "update:"+ updatedEvent.id);
                handleUpdate(response.data);
                setCategory(1);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                // handle error response
                console.log(error);
            });
    };

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (!eventName || !eventDate) {
            setErrorMessage("Please fill all the gaps");
            return;
        }
        const updatedEvent = {
            id: initialValues ? initialValues.id : null,
            eventName: initialValues.eventName,
            eventDate: initialValues.eventDate,
            category: 1,
        };
        console.log("date:" + eventDate);
        onUpdate(updatedEvent);
        onClose();
        onReload();
    };


return (

    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                            <label htmlFor="eventName" className="block text-gray-700 font-bold mb-2">
                                                Event Name
                                            </label>
                                            <input
                                                type="text"
                                                id="eventName"
                                                name="eventName"
                                                className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                                                value={eventName}
                                                onChange={handleDescriptionChange}
                                                maxLength={255}
                                            />
                                            {errorMessage && (
                                                <p className="text-red-500 text-xs italic mt-2">{errorMessage}</p>
                                            )}
                                            <div className="mb-4">
                                                <label htmlFor="eventDate" className="block text-gray-700 font-bold mb-2">
                                                    Event Date
                                                </label>
                                                <input
                                                    type="date"
                                                    id="eventDate"
                                                    name="eventDate"
                                                    className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                                                    value={eventDate}
                                                    onChange={handleDateChange}
                                                />
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="flex justify-end">
                                                <button
                                                    type="submit"
                                                    className="inline-flex justify-center px-4 py-2 border border-transparent text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-blue-500"
                                                    onClick={(event) => handleSubmit(event, id)}
                                                >
                                                    Update
                                                </button>
                                                <button
                                                    type="button"
                                                    className="ml-2 inline-flex justify-center px-4 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md text-gray-700 bg-white hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-blue-500"
                                                    onClick={onClose}
                                                >
                                                    Cancel
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                        

);
```

**Update method:**

```
public void Update(Event eventElemnt, int user_id)
        {
            if (eventElemnt == null || user_id < 0 || user_id.GetType() != typeof(int))
            {
                throw new InvalidInput("Invalid inputs");
            }
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("Omega_Conn")))
            {
                query = "UPDATE Event SET event_name = @event_name, event_date = @event_date, fk_event_category = @event_category " +
                    "WHERE fk_event_user = @user_id ;";
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@event_name", eventElemnt.Event_name);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@event_date", eventElemnt.Event_date);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@event_category", 1);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_id", user_id);

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
```

**model Event:**

```
using Omega.Interfaces.Base;
using System;

namespace Omega.Models
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents an event with a name, date, user and category.
    /// </summary>
    public class Event : IBase
    {
      


        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the ID of the event.
        /// </summary>
        public int Id { get ; set ; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the name of the event.
        /// </summary>
        public string? Event_name { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the date of the event.
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime Event_date { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the ID of the user who created the event.
        /// </summary>
        public int Fk_event_user { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the ID of the category of the event.
        /// </summary>
        public int Fk_event_category { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Debug your web API and read the exception details. We can't help you without the exception message/log is provided.

Comment: I assume you mean what I am getting in console.log(error)?

Comment: @Peter_Griffindor, no, he means the details of the ex object in the catch blocks of your Put method, the Exception type and StackTrace along with the Message would be useful

Comment: 500 Internal server error status code is returned from Web API, it will be straightforward that you debug the code and read the exception in API side.

Comment: @YongShun An error occurred: `SqlDateTime overflow`, but I have the same DateTime format in Database and in model class

Comment: And what would this mythical `DateTime` value you are trying to save be? We would love to  know, particularly since it's at the root the problem.

Comment: What does the `Event` class look like?

Comment: From the `<input type="date">` in format 2023-04-15

Comment: @JuanR I have added `Event` model to my question

Comment: What you need to be looking at in a debugging session is the value of the field itself, not what you typed. What is the value of the field `Event_date` before you try to save and where is the code that saves to the database?

Comment: @JuanR Before updating is the value `2023-04-05 22:00:00.000`, the Update method is in question

Comment: The problem is with Event object `eventData`. It does not contain any data according to debugging

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is on the `handleSubmit` method. You are always sending initial values back in the API call and your property names don't match:

```
const updatedEvent = {
    id: initialValues ? initialValues.id : null,
    eventName: initialValues.eventName,
    eventDate: initialValues.eventDate,
    category: 1,
};
```

You should change this to send the data collected. I don't know what `Id` is, so I won't mess with that, but the name, date and category:

```
const updatedEvent = {
    Id: initialValues ? initialValues.id : null,
    Event_name: eventName,
    Event_date: eventDate,
    Fk_event_category: category,
};
```

You are seeing this error because by not passing a value (your initial `eventDate` value is an empty string), your server side object's property (which is not nullable) is defaulting to the min C# value for a `DateTime` object which is `January 1, 0001 00:00:00`. SQL server's minimum date value is `January 1, 1753`, thereby causing an overflow error.

Comment: I agree that problem is in `handleSubmit` method. How I sad `[FromBody] Event eventData` are not correct pass from `Form`.  `id: initialValues ? initialValues.id : null,` is `id` of the Event

Comment: I found the problem.... Please see my answer

Comment: @Peter_Griffindor I edited the answer. Even with the right property names, you would have still had a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in `handleSubmit` method, where properties did not match properties from model

```
using Omega.Interfaces.Base;
using System;

namespace Omega.Models
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents an event with a name, date, user and category.
    /// </summary>
    public class Event : IBase
    {
      


        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the ID of the event.
        /// </summary>
        public int Id { get ; set ; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the name of the event.
        /// </summary>
        public string? Event_name { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the date of the event.
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime Event_date { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the ID of the user who created the event.
        /// </summary>
        public int Fk_event_user { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the ID of the category of the event.
        /// </summary>
        public int Fk_event_category { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then in **EditEvent** component:

```
 const updatedEvent = {
                id: initialValues ? initialValues.id : null,
                Event_name: eventName,
                Event_date: eventDate,
                Fk_event_category: category,
            };
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).